# Runtime Button Background Color Change but it not Stays in Rounded Corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am having issue that I am having two button i set Backgroung with rounded_corner.xml.. Now, if i change the background color runtime then it removes the rounded corner.. How to solve this issue..If anybody face this problem then share with me..Thank you..

My rounded_xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="@color/green" /> 
  <corners android:radius="3dp" /> 
  <gradient android:startColor="@color/green" android:centerColor="@color/green" android:endColor="@color/green" android:angle="90" /> 
</shape>
```

And this is my two buttons..

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_custom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:text="Accer is the Best"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="5dp" android:gravity="left"/>



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:textColor="@color/white" android:textStyle="bold" android:padding="5dp" android:text="HP is the Best" android:gravity="left"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically) should help you.

Comment: can u xplain a bit what exactly u want to achieve??