# How can i keep the borders on a view while changing dynamically its background color?

Tags: android, layout, colors, background

I applied borders on a linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:background="@drawable/linearborder2" />
```

and in my main activity i want to change dynamically the background color of this one, but i do that the borders fade away. 
So how can i do to keep these borders and change the color?

Thank you

Comment: Well.. use another drawable with border..!

Comment: how to do that ? in my main activity i wrote vi.setBackgroundColor(color) color is the new color chosen

Comment: You should create another drawable.. Just like "linearborder2"

Comment: linearborder2 is a xml file, how can i put a dynamic variable (which is the color) in a xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `linearborder2` is a shape drawable.You can change the color of a shape drawable dynamically. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically) should help with that.

Comment: i tried this one:GradientDrawable sd = (GradientDrawable) tv2.getBackground().mutate();
sd.setColor(color);
sd.invalidateSelf(); & this one i found on the post you gave me ShapeDrawable bgShape = (ShapeDrawable )btn.getBackground();
bgShape.getPaint().setColor(Color); but i got a null exception pointer on both