# How to pass the color value dynamically to xml

Tags: android, xml, colors

i have a xml which will draw oval shape , the code is below:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#61118"/>
    <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#1B434D" />
</shape>
```

Now i here `android:color="#61118"` i need to pass the value from java class, Is it possible?

If not is there any alternative way?

Comment: Would this question be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically ?

Comment: No. you cannot pass value that value.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly you cannot pass arguments to XML Drawables.

If you don't have too many different values, you can use a [`<level-list>`](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#level-list) and provide different versions of your shape.

Then you would change the level associated with your drawable to change the color using [`Drawable.setLevel(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setLevel%28int%29).

---

**my_drawable.xml**

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="@color/border" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:maxLevel="1">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="@color/border" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:maxLevel="2">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</level-list>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```java
// myView is a View (or a subclass of View) 
// with background set to R.drawable.my_drawable
myView.getBackground().setLevel(0); // Set color to red
myView.getBackground().setLevel(1); // Set color to green
myView.getBackground().setLevel(2); // Set color to blue

// myImageView is an ImageView with its source
// set to R.drawable.my_drawable
myImageView.setImageLevel(0); // Set color to red
myImageView.setImageLevel(1); // Set color to green
myImageView.setImageLevel(2); // Set color to blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the color of a shape dynamically.
Assume your xml is in, 'res/drawable/oval_shape.xml'

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oval_shape);
int argb = 0x12345678;
shape.setBackground( argb );
```

if you would like to change the border color

```
int width = 1;
int argb = 0x87654321;
shape.setStroke( width, argb );
```

This solution provides more flexibility over using a level-list because you are not tied to using a view to set the level.