# how to convert shape to ShapDrawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, shapes

I have a number of shapes, and I have one view. I need to dynamically (i.e. programmatically) select a shape to set as the background of my view based on user inputs. So my question: who do I programmatically turn a shape into a ShapeDrawable or such?

I already look at [How to change shape color dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically). Those posts assume the shape is already attached to a view. But me all my shapes are free agents.

Comment: How are you having the shape information?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is does not work with *ShapeDrawable*, but take a look at my *GradientDrawable* example:

you can create gradient drawable dynamically.. use below class

```
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;

public class SomeDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

public SomeDrawable(int pStartColor, int pCenterColor, int pEndColor, int pStrokeWidth, int pStrokeColor, float cornerRadius) {
    super(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,new int[]{pStartColor,pCenterColor,pEndColor});
    setStroke(pStrokeWidth,pStrokeColor);
    setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
}
```

}

and use this class as below

```
SomeDrawable drawable = new SomeDrawable(Color.parseColor("Start Color Code"),Color.parseColor("Center Color Code"),Color.parseColor("End Color Code"),1,Color.BLACK,00);
yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I can do

```
myview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shape)
```