# Lollipop's backgroundTint has no effect on a Button

Tags: android, android-layout, tint

I have a Button in my Activity, and I'd like it to have my theme's accent color.
Instead of making my own drawables like we had to do pre-Lollipop, naturally I'd like to use the new `backgroundTint` attribute.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddCode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    android:text="@string/addressInfo_edit_addCode" />
```

Unfortunately it has no effect, the button stays gray.

I tried different values for `backgroundTintMode`, which didn't change anything.

I also tried doing it programmatically in my Activity, which didn't change anything.

```
addCodeView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddCode).setBackgroundTintList(
     getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.accent));
```

**Why is my tint ignored?**

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I am indeed testing on a Lollipop device.
Other widgets (e.g. EditText) are correctly and automatically tinted.

Comment: This is a bug that has been fixed for a future release, but the accepted solution will work on API 21+.

Comment: check this [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35867955/2826147)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tested on API 19 through API 27

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/retry"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

produces output as -

[image]

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer because after several years, I believe it's now currently the official (and best) way to do this. (Minor detail: I'm pretty sure in most cases you can simply use Button instead of AppCompatButton and it will still work).

Answer (score 118):

### The bad news

Like BoD says, it's meaningless to tint a Button's background in Lollipop 5.0 (API level 21).

### The good news

Lollipop 5.1 (API level 22) seems to have fixed this by changing btn_mtrl_default_shape.xml (among other files): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6dfa60f33ca6018959ebff1efde82db7d2aed1e3%5E!/#F0

### The great news

The new support library (version 22.1+) [adds backward-compatible tinting support](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) to lots of components, including [AppCompatButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)!

Unfortunately, the `android:backgroundTint` property still doesn't work (maybe I'm doing something wrong) -- so you have to set the `ColorStateList` in code, using [`setSupportBackgroundTintList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html#setSupportBackgroundTintList%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29). It'd be really nice to see `android:backgroundTint` supported in the future. **Update**: Marcio Granzotto commented that `app:backgroundTint` works on AppCompatButton! Note that it's `app:`, not `android:`, because it's in the app/library.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing, testing"
        app:backgroundTint="#ff00ff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your activity will automatically inflate an `AppCompatButton` instead of the normal `Button` if you let it inherit from `AppCompatActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatButton v = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xffffcc00});
        v.setSupportBackgroundTintList(csl);
    }
}
```

You should of course get the `ColorStateList` from a color resource, but I was lazy, so...

<sup><sub>Oh, and don't forget to base your app theme on one of the `Theme.AppCompat` themes, or the compat views will be very, very sad... ;)</sub></sup>

This worked on both 2.3.7 (Gingerbread MR1) and 5.0 (Lollipop 'Classic').

Comment: Just added some more info -- most importantly, it's now possible to achieve button tinting with the new version (22.1) of the support library that was released the other day!

Comment: You can use `colorButtonNormal` with AppCompat 22.1.1 (setting the theme only for the buttons), it works for me on 4.4.4 and 5.1.

Comment: Indeed, and BoD already informed us thusly below.

One downside to that method is that setting android:theme on a button makes its context a ContextThemeWrapper (wrapping the activity) instead of just the plain Activity. This means that, for example, the android:onClick attribute doesn't work as expected (it fails to find your method in the wrapper class).

Comment: Any idea how to set the same thing for TextView ?

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Using setSupportBackgroundTintList I can't achieve a colored Ripple. What state do I have to override in the ColorStateList?

Comment: Just use         <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondary</item> and it works from styles

Comment: Instead of `new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xffffcc00});` you can write more concisely `ColorStateList.valueOf(0xffffcc00);`.

Comment: You can use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with app:backgroundTint on the xml

Comment: The error is still present on devices running Android Lolipop 5.0.x using support library 23.1.1 (current version at time of writing). app:backgroundTint will be ignored for AppCompatButton. No problems on devices with API-Level <= 19 or >= 22.

Answer (score 30):

It seems that tinting a ripple drawable is meaningless (and the default background of a button is a ripple drawable).

In fact, after looking at the platform's default button drawable, I found the "correct" way to do this:.  You have to define this in your theme:

```
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/accent</item>
```

(Of course this is only for level 21+.)

Warning: since this is defined in a theme, this will use the given color for all the buttons (at least all of the buttons in activities using that theme.)

As a bonus, you can also change the ripple color by defining this:

```
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/accent_ripple</item>
```

Comment: `colorControlHighlight` would change a lot of other widgets though. Glad you've worked it out.

Comment: You can apply this to an individual view by defining an overlay theme (e.g. no parent theme and only one attribute defined) and using the android:theme attribute.

Comment: Then how it is fixed for API 22 and up? Also this "bug" occours only in some devices of API 21 (including nexus 5, galaxy s3)

Answer (score 22):

To resolve issues related to tinting on Android 5.0.x I use something like this:

```
public static void setButtonTint(Button button, ColorStateList tint) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && button instanceof AppCompatButton) {
        ((AppCompatButton) button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(tint);
    } else {
        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, tint);
    }
}
```

It uses the support method only for API 21 and the ViewCompat one for all other cases.

Comment: @Marco Use: `if (view instanceof TintableBackgroundView) { ((TintableBackgroundView) view).setSupportBackgroundTintList(tint); } else { ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, tint); }`

Comment: This doesnt work with an ImageButton on pre lollipop devices.

Comment: I get a lint warning when using AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList()

AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Comment: It worked for me but I had to invert the conditions.

Comment: "can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support" why this warning?

Answer (score 22):

I usually do it dynamically by using PorterDuff:

```
mbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mbutton.getBackground().setColorFilter(anycolor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

You can check different blending modes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) and nice examples [here](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html).

Comment: I have used PorterDuff.Mode.SRC and it works perfectly

Comment: Works perfectly. In my case i wanted to use tinting effect on API 17, this helped me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Confirm working on API 20.

Answer (score 20):

Just use `app:backgroundTint` instead of `android:backgroundTint`, the tint will take effect below Lollipop. The reason is `AppCompatActivity` use `AppCompatViewInflater` to auto change Button or TextView to AppCompatButton or AppCompatTextView, then `app:backgroundTint` take effect.

[image]

[In my project I used it, it worked.](https://github.com/drakeet/TimeMachine/commit/e288a2bb107de0d96981f5714fa2c6ccedb8ae34)

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to have `android:background` set to make `android:backgroundTint` work.

To be more accurate, my guess is that you can't `backgroundTint` the default button background from Material themes, which is defined as a `RippleDrawable`.

Comment: I think you are correct.  In fact I found the "correct" way to do what I want (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

Just use app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint

Comment: This worked instantly. I still don't understand why it seems to work across ALL API versions.

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue was reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201873

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)  (March 2016) **This bug is solved.**

**Issue : FloatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(@Nullable ColorStateList tint) no longer changes background color**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`

Use **design support library(23.2.1)** and **appcompatwidgets**  as below

**[Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)** :

> AppCompat (aka ActionBarCompat) started out as a backport of the
>   Android 4.0 ActionBar API for devices running on Gingerbread,
>   providing a common API layer on top of the backported implementation
>   and the framework implementation. AppCompat v21 delivers an API and
>   feature-set that is up-to-date with Android 5.0

---

**[Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)** :

> The ability to tint widgets automatically when using AppCompat is
>   incredibly helpful in keeping strong branding and consistency
>   throughout your app. This is done automatically when inflating layouts
>   - replacing Button with AppCompatButton, TextView with AppCompatTextView, etc. to ensure that each could support tinting. In
>   this release, those tint aware widgets are now publicly available,
>   allowing you to keep tinting support even if you need to subclass one
>   of the supported widgets.

Answer (score 2):

If we look into the source code of Support Library, we see that it tints normally it's known buttons, but if we change the shape of our button (I have round button) tint doesn't work ok in api<=21.
We can also see that TintManager became public class (appcompat-v7:23.1.1), so we can take ColorStateList from default button shape (which is tinted ok in 5.0) for current theme (so we don't have to create the array of colors):

```
    Context c = ...; // activity
    AppCompatButton ab = ...; // your button
    // works ok in 22+:
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 21) {
        // default appcompat button, that is tinted ok with current theme colors "abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape":
        // ColorStateList tint = TintManager.get(c).getTintList(R.drawable.abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape);
        // Appcompat 23.2 change:
        ColorStateList tint = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getTintList(c, R.drawable.abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape);
        ab.setSupportBackgroundTintList(tint);
        }
```

Comment: since appcompat 23.2 they changed the class (though its public!)

TintManager -> AppCompatDrawableManager

the code stays almost the same

Comment: WTF... getTintList changed from public to protected now ;( need to use reflection :)

Answer (score 0):

Because attribute `backgroundTint` is only used in API level 21 and higher

Comment: I realize that, and I am indeed testing on a Lollipop device.  I will update the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware recyclerview most updated lib  can cause this bug as well.

This command

```
  sendBtnView.setBackgroundTintList(colorState)
```

worked perfectly in the past but stop working for me. after research it turns out the cause is the lib that was addeded to gradle dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

So I tried to change it to 23.02.1 as it was recommended here in Amit Vaghela post.
I changed to

```
  compile  'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.02.1'
```

But gradle error said recyclerview lib  does not  have this version (23.02.1) (gradle could not find it in Jcenter raw.github or repo).

Then, becaouse I knew setBackgroundTintList command used to worke well  in the past with version 22.02.0' in all the other libs I have in gradle dependencies. 
so I change it to:

```
compile   'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.02.0'
```

And now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is recommended but you can try this:

```
Drawable newDrawable = mBtnAction.getBackground();  // obtain Bg drawable from the button as a new drawable
DrawableCompat.setTint(newDrawable, mActivity.getHomeTobBarBGColor());  //set it's tint
mBtnAction.setBackground(newDrawable);  //apply back to button
```

In a general sense it works. Tried `ViewCompat` but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `backgroundTint` `<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton` with `"com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01"` version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using androidx then adding both prefixed and not prefixed version resolved issue on android 5.1:

```
<style name="Button_Primary">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_primary_selector</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_primary_selector</item><!--needed for android 5-->
</style>
```

button_primary selector is in `color` folder with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</selector>
```

and apply it on regular button on `AppCompatActivity`

```
<Button style="@style/Button_Primary"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an app that your target `sdk` is higher than api 21 and your `minSdkVersion is 21(Lollipop)` instead of

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
```

you can simply say..

```
android:background="@color/accent"
```