# Raised and flat buttons with different background and highlight colors

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm creating application using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` library.

I define application theme in `values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/highlight_dark</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme"></style>
```

I use AppCompat `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` style for raised button and  and `Widget.AppComap.Button.Borderless.Colored` style for flat buttons.

`colorAccent` theme attribute defines raised button background color and flat button text color but I suppose that it's a bug because these colors should be defined by `colorButtonNormal` attribute, as it does for `Widget.AppCompat.Button` and `Widget.AppComap.Button.Borderless` styles.

`colorControlHighlight` theme attribute defines `ripple` color for both buttons.

Questions are:

1. How can I use raised buttons with different colors? For example, I want buttons with primary and accent colors.
2. My accent color is not light, so raised button has saturated background and `colorControlHighlight` should be light (`#40ffffff`). But flat button has transparent background and `colorControlHighlight` should be dark (`#40000000`) for it. How can I set different `ripple` colors for raised and flat buttons?

I added my current solution below, but I can't help feeling that I missed something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research and googling I defined separate themes for different raised and flat buttons:

```
<style name="AppTheme.RaisedButton">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.RaisedButton.Primary">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.RaisedButton.Accent">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.FlatButton">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/highlight_light</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.FlatButton.Primary">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.FlatButton.Accent">
</style>
```

Note, that I'm using `buttonStyle` attribute not `android:buttonStyle` because it will not work on pre-lollipop devices.

Use these themes in `android:theme` attribute:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_button"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FlatButton.Primary" />
```

Comment: Solid answer it's silly how the docs are the how not the what.

Comment: Sweet Jesus! Why doesn't Google provide info like this is beyond me !! This document here should show the styling XML too http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types