# Set different color to buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have 6 buttons and want to set colour of 5 buttons to ORANGE (`#F08C35`) and the last one to PINK(`#D81B60`). I have created styles (styles.xml) for each one as;

```
    <style name="MagentaButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#D81B60</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OrangeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#F08C35</item>
    </style>
```

However all the buttons are set to `colorAccent (#FF4081)` as it picks the accent color from `parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"`.

I tried setting the `android:background` attr however the entire space of the button changes to the set background and I lose out on the raised button effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.sameer.android.myappportfolio.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/app0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="@style/MagentaButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/app6" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

styles.xml pasted below:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="MagentaButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#D81B60</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
    </style>
    <style name="OrangeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#F08C35</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Maybe its easier to just set the color to each button? styles are usually applied when you want it across all the app.

Comment: set your color as background

Comment: As I have mentioned above set the background makes the button to carry a borderless or flat look and feel. I need the raised one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542303/raised-and-flat-buttons-with-different-background-and-highlight-colors try this if this helps you

Comment: @ParthAnjaria I had referred to it however it didn't serve my purpose.

Comment: then u need to make a drawable with shadow and set it as background

Comment: @Sameer check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `backgroundTint`, that's all.
Also, if you need it on pre-L use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`
and `app:backgroundTint`, instead of `android:backgroundTint`

Comment: Thanks @dtk12! I had returned this one too before posting my query. However no success :-). Tried again now with AppCompatButton too

Comment: Are you sure that you used `app:backgroundTint` not `android:backgroundTint` with `AppCompatButton`? Because for me it works fine.

Comment: Yes. I included app:XXXX too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<style name="MagentaButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#D81B60</item>
</style>

<style name="OrangeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#F08C35</item>
</style>
```

You should set the parent to `"Widget.AppCompat.Button"` instead of `"Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"`. "Raised button effect" is preserved with this solution as you wanted.

#### edit:

You should use your style like this to apply it to the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:theme="@style/OrangeButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/app1" />
```

Use attribute `android:theme=` instead of `style=`. It will work.

Comment: Thanks I had tried it already. However it didn't work for me. I am trying it on emulator.

Comment: @Sameer It's strange, because it SHOULD work. Could you edit your question and show your button in xml layout file?

Comment: Thanks @6franek. No success yet!

Comment: Also a style would make more sense here compared to a theme in this context.

Answer (score -1):

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <gradient
     android:startColor="@color/drk_button"
     android:endColor="@color/lgt_button"
     android:angle="90">
   </gradient>

   <corners android:radius="20dip" />

   <stroke
     android:width="1px"
     android:color="@color/drk_button" />
</shape>
```

try this if this helps. you will need to set color .
hope this helps