# Coloring Buttons in Android with AppCompat

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Does anyone know how to change the button color?

but one particular button, not all the buttons of the application using the XML.

> The android:backgroundTint attribute doesn't work on pre-Lollipop even
>   with AppCompat library. Only colorButtonNormal from theme works on
>   pre-Lollipop.

Is that true? what a shame

I'm using this drawable (is a simple green color) with a button, but when I use the button turns out to be higher than the normal button.

this is the file **btn_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff5722" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#4caf50" />

        <corners android:radius="4dip" />

        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#F0FC00" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="#4caf50" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

the button is this:

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnIngresar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

when i use the drawable, the button is higher than the normal button (without the drawable), i don't know why.

Comment: Are you using an AppCompat theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way to set the `BackgroundTint` in pre-lollipop devices. Try this:
`button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.accentColor));`
Refer to this Answer: [Lollipop's backgroundTint has no effect on a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button)

Comment: Now you should use `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, colorList)` instead of `button.setSupportBackgroundTintList`

Comment: but in the XML is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 9):

if you want below style

[image]

add this style your button

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
```

if you want this style

[image]

add below code

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```