# Why Button.setColorFilter only works in lollipop devices?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme, android-styles

I am using API level 17 and these are my relevant dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

This is the definition of my button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonConsultarCodigoQR"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="15dp"
android:onClick="consultarCodigoQR"
android:text="@string/label_button_consultar_codigo_QR" />
```

This is where I try to make my button have a little green color:

```
Button buttonConsultarCodigoQR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConsultarCodigoQR);
// this line has no effect in pre-lollipop devices, why?
buttonConsultarCodigoQR.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF7FBEB8, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

What am I missing ? the color of the button in pre-lollipop devices is grey, but otherwise is of the green-like color that I set in the code (0xFF7FBEB8)

Comment: What kind of backgrounds does your button have? I'm interested in the exact class, on both Lollipop and the older release. You should be able to get this info by just printing the Drawable returned from `getBackground()`.

Comment: For example, the `ColorDrawable` class [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29) says this about `setColorFilter()`: `Only supported on version LOLLIPOP and above. Calling this method has no effect on earlier versions`. Might be that you have a ColorDrawable, might be that you have some other Drawable type with the same behavior.

Comment: On Gingerbread, with Theme.AppCompat and an AppCompatButton, the background appears to be an `InsetDrawable` wrapping a `GradientDrawable`. The [drawing code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java#249) looks reasonable to me, seemingly applying the filter as intended -- but I must be missing something, because it does indeed not work.

Comment: I've compared the Gingerbread and Lollipop `draw()` code for GradientDrawable, and I can't find any differences that I would consider to affect this... Anyways, maybe you could just use [tinting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button) instead?