# Android setBackgroundTintList on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, floating-action-button, setbackground

I'm working with `FloatingActionButton`.
The user should be able to switch the FAB background color within a `onClick` Event.

However, the recommended call to `setBackgroundTintList` seems to be only compatible from 21+ API.

How do I - correctly - go about it on pre-lollipop devices? Is there any alternative I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30313299/4385913)

Comment: @Skizo Thank you! Wasn't aware of that ViewCompat call (neither of the setSupportBackgroundTintList). Please write your own answer so that I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36006440/2826147).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use also [`setSupportBackgroundTintList`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/TintableBackgroundView.html#setSupportBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

> Applies a tint to the background drawable. Does not modify the current tint mode, which is SRC_IN by default.
>
> Subsequent calls to View.setBackground(Drawable) will automatically mutate the drawable and apply the specified tint and tint mode.

Also take a look on [`ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList))

> Applies a tint to the background drawable.
>
> This will always take effect when running on API v21 or newer. When running on platforms previous to API v21, it will only take effect if view implement the TintableBackgroundView interface.

I found a solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30313299/4385913) that I've used before and is this:

```
public static void setButtonTint(Button button, ColorStateList tint) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && button instanceof AppCompatButton) {
      ((AppCompatButton) button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(tint);
  } else {
      ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, tint);
  }
}
```

It works for me I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: Thanks upvote and mark it as a correct answer if it was what you needed :P Glad to hear that.

Comment: But FloatingActionButton does not implement TintableBackgroundView, so the ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList() does not work for API < 21

Comment: I get a lint warning when using AppCompatButton.setBackgroundTintList()

AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Comment: @starkej2 may you post a question with images related with your issue and link here your question link? I'll try to help you :D

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I think all you need to do is call ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, tint) regardless of API level

Comment: ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, tint); is working for my AppCompatButton button's on API 19/Kit Kat. This answer's IF should really be checking for Lollipop and below.

Answer (score 10):

simple:

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(0xFF4CAF50));
```

`fab` is your `FloatingActionButton` of course and `0xFF4CAF50` just a example color

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I meant. Check @Skizo answer for further clarification. Thank you by the way! :)

Comment: is this way backward compatible

Comment: @Matteo FAB implementation comes from support lib and it does support backward compatibility. Underneath `setBackgroundTintList()` is using different impl for pre-lolipop. Proven on KitKat device.

Answer (score 0):

From XML, you can use

```
card_view:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"
```

where `card_view` is `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`