# backgroundTint has not effect on lollipop version

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have set the the **backgroundTint** of a view as shown below but it has no effect on its color. On xml design view, it looks fine but not on the device. I have lollipop's version on my device.

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 21.

```
<View
   android:layout_width="35dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp"                     
   android:background="@drawable/circle_appointment_statuses"
   android:backgroundTint="@color/pending" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lollipop's backgroundTint has no effect on a Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button)

Comment: No, In that case its a button and it was handled by overriding an attribute "android:colorButtonNormal" in the theme. But in this case its a View.

Answer (score 2):

To tint a background drawable on a View on Lollipop (API 21), use `setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)`.

```
layout.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color), PorterDuff.Mode.SCR_ATOP)
```

The following methods DO NOT work on background drawables on Lollipop.

`background.setTint(int color)`

`DrawableCompat.setTint(Drawable drawable, int color)`

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? The described API behavior is accurate.

Comment: This is the only way that background drawable can be tint for ViewGroups in Lollipop.

Comment: Exactly! This is the only way but this answer got downvoted for some reason.

Comment: Its `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP`

Answer (score 1):

**The bad news**

it's meaningless to tint a Button's background in Lollipop 5.0 (API level 21).

**The good news**

Lollipop 5.1 (API level 22) seems to have fixed this by changing btn_mtrl_default_shape.xml (among other files): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6dfa60f33ca6018959ebff1efde82db7d2aed1e3%5E!/#F0

**The great news**

The new support library (version 22.1+) [adds backward-compatible tinting support](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) to lots of components, including [AppCompatButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html)!

Unfortunately, the android:backgroundTint property still doesn't work (maybe I'm doing something wrong) -- so you have to set the ColorStateList in code, using setSupportBackgroundTintList(). It'd be really nice to see android:backgroundTint supported in the future.

More Detail visit here.[Lollipop's backgroundTint has no effect on a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button)

Comment: yeah i have read it, already. Its useful but not an accepted answer.