# button changing xml android studio

Tags: java, android

I am just trying to do some basic coding.
I have a button which when clicked I want it to change the tint color of a drawable image I have. But I am not sure how I can change the tint when the button is pressed.
Any help would be most welcome!

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button myYellow_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Yellow_Button);


        myYellow_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {


                box.setBackground(colorPrimary);

            }


}
```

I am not sure how to reference the XML script to change the Tint, I have experimented with SetBackground but I haven't got anywhere with it.

Comment: Refer this post:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button

Comment: Please include the code you've already tried.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a binding to your `ImageView` by using `myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewId);`.

Then, in the `onClick()` method your button click listener, you need to do something like : `myImageView.setColorFilter(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.whatevercolor));`.

Another solution is to have 2 versions of your drawable, with the 2 colors you want, and change the `ImageView.Image` field dynamically :

```
myImageView.setImage(new Image(R.drawable.yourSecondDrawable));
```

Comment: I managed to do the solution number 2 already, but I want to give the user more options that just pre-saved images. which is why I want there to be a color spectrum available once I figure out how to connect the button to the xml;

Comment: Be aware that using solution number 2 will make your app slower and bigger (in storage), because you manipulate images instead of color values.

Comment: Hi Maxime I agree, but it was a good place to start and build on.

Comment: Maxime when I try the code you posted I get an issue with the 'set.ColorTint' and the 'yellow', it is not recognised, here is the code I have: 
final ImageView box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Test_Box);
Button myYellow_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Yellow_Button);
 myYellow_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                box.setColorTint(getResources().getString(R.color.yellow));
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks Maxine, in the end I used the following, but only after fiddling with the code you posted;

Comment: box.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

Comment: but I think the getColor is old code...but it works ! :)

Comment: Yes it's deprecated. Use ResourceCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yourcolor) instead

Comment: This doesn't work I think it needs something after the getContext() as it does not recognise the the symbol variable R after it. also do I need to put 'android' in there for it to recognise the color white?