# android - ViewCompat setBackgroundTintList not working in API 21

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a *AppCompatEditText* with the property *backgroundTint* setted to an specific color.
 I've created a method to change the background tint programmatically and its working in all Android versions since API 17 (4.2 Jelly Bean) to API 25 (7.1.1 Nougat), **except API 21 (5.0 Lollipop)**.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
    public void changeViewBackgroundColor(Context context, View view, int color) {
      int theColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color);

      if (view instanceof TintableBackgroundView) {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(theColor);
        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, colorStateList);
      } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(theColor);
      }

      view.invalidate();
  }
```

Comment: Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742423/6723193).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735890/lollipops-backgroundtint-has-no-effect-on-a-button

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in API 21 was introduced a change that broke `setBackgroundTintList` when use from `ViewCompat` or the view itself (later fixed in API 22).

In its place you should use `setSupportBackgroundTintList` which you can find as a member of **AppCompat*** views (like `AppCompatEditText`)

```
AppCompatEditText editText = findViewById(R.id.your_view);
editText.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
```

If you want to set it in **XML**, just use `app:setBackgroundTintList` from the support library, instead of `android:setBackgroundTintList`

Comment: I was having a headache until finding this. Thank you