# How to customize custom drawable defined in XML at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-attributes

I made a custom, multi-layered drawable to act as the background for a button. Sometimes, I want part of this drawable layer to be blue. Sometimes I want it to be green. Point is, it's a variable, and I want it to be definable in the associated custom view XML.

Is this possible? How do I write a drawable in XML whose value I can determine at runtime?

**custom_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
    android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />
        <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
            android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
            android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
            android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

The line `<solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />` is what I want to set at runtime. I have my custom view for this class already receiving the color value I want to use here - how do I apply it to the XML of this drawable?

Comment: Don't know if there is a way to modify the custom logic programatically at runtime.  You might just have to create two custom_button.xml files and choose them appropriately when you want one over the other.

Comment: @JaySnayder I'm actually trying to create a library for the custom button view that lets me easily modify the value used in this drawable

Comment: Extracting the shape into a drawable and maybe then you can change it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
InsetDrawable drawable = (InsetDrawable) myButton.getBackground();
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) drawable.getDrawable();
shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

> I made a custom, multi-layered drawable to act as the background for a button.

This assumes `myButton` is the button which you refer to above and has been defined with

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
```

EDIT

For an API level 1 way to do this:

Make a `custom_shape.xml` drawable:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />
    <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
        android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
</shape>
```

Write a method to change the colour of this drawable and put an inset around it:

```
private void changeColor() {
    // Get shape from XML
    GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_shape);
    shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    // Programmatically create Inset
    InsetDrawable drawable =  new InsetDrawable(shape,
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_horizontal_material),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_vertical_material),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_horizontal_material),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.button_inset_vertical_material));

    // Apply to button
    myButton.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? This would not be using the custom_button.xml drawable I have defined

Comment: Yes it would. `getBackground()` returns the `InsetDrawable` you created in `custom_button.xml`, provided you have set it as the background for your button, as you stated.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully this will work. It looks like gradientDrawable.getDrawable() is KITKAT or above though

Comment: is there any way to do this using an Inset still?

Comment: this library is meant to work on ICS or above, but 4.1 would be okay too.

Comment: See my edit above. You need to create a seperate drawable just for the shape, then wrap the inset around it programmatically.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Why is it important that the background has been defined with `android:background="@drawable/custom_button"`. I have noticed that the ripple selector uses strange colors if you set the background programmatically, instead of via XML. I need to do it programmatically and not with XML.

Comment: How are you making it "act as the background to a button" if not by setting the background to the drawable? What ripple selector? You don't mention in in your question. I feel I have answered your question as best as I can - perhaps someone else will come along and answer your follow up questions. Good luck! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71612/discussion-between-zaktaccardi-and-ken-wolf).