# I have two button for which i create the XML to make buttons round.But I want to give the different color to both button

Tags: android

Here I am writing the code of XML That I am using to change the background of button.

**roundbutton2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eea0e5ee"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Buttons snippet**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:id="@+id/bt_clear"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background = "@drawable/roundbutton2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="Proceed"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/bt_proceed"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:background = "@drawable/roundbutton2"/>
```

For first i want the #EE494D4E color and for second button i want #eea0e5ee.How can do this.
I want the different color for both button using same XML file.
Please Tell me about this.Thanx

Comment: Have you tried to use two different drawables?

Answer (score 0):

In your `roundbutton2.xml` you are directly setting the color of the shape value to `#eea0e5ee` which causes your buttons that set it as a background to have that color. What I did was remove the `<solid android:color="#eea0e5ee"/>` and set the `backgroundTint` via the xml to your preferred color, like so:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_clear"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton2"
        android:backgroundTint="#EE494D4E"
        android:text="Clear"

        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_proceed"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton2"
        android:backgroundTint="#eea0e5ee"
        android:text="Proceed"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
```

**NOTE**: This is just a workaround. I'm not entirely sure if this should be done, or is against best practice. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34412060/4625829) is my reference. If you still want the default color value of your button to stay, the only way you could achieve changing the color of other buttons is [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165050/4625829).

Cheers! :D