# Create drawable programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I create this exact drawable in java code only?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="-15px"
        android:top="-5px" />
</shape>
```

I need the padding values to be variable so I can't do it as an xml.

Comment: `How can I create this exact drawable in java code only?` By drawing on the canvas.

Comment: Hope you can get hint from here [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically)

Comment: see `GradientDrawable` docurmntation

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna draw something custom, you should open a Canvas and make your drawing there.

Read this:
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

And it seems a simple shape. So you can add a layout view (View,TextView, ImageView, etc.) set background with this drawable and adjust padding through this view.