# how to set a solid color programatically?

Tags: android, textview

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/colorTurquoiseBlue" />
    <solid android:color="#33d1a3" />
    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

below `textview`:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_rounded_corner"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Added"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
```

I am calling textview_rounded_corner in background in `textview` I have to set 
 programmatically in adapter can any one please suggest me how to achieve this I  dont want to create three different  xml for three different color i want set   programmatically.

Comment: can u explain me more

Comment: Try this :

((GradientDrawable)YOUR_AppCompatTextView.getBackground()).setColor(someColor);

Comment: for reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164630/how-to-change-shape-color-dynamically

Comment: i have  set rounded corner in text view with blue color  but in solid color is s different   that solid color i want set progrmatically like  for green ,red ,yellow

Comment: https://snag.gy/vQHX7O.jpg check this @Mohit

Comment: check this @MohammadAli

Comment: i am unable to get which color you are trying to change...if you want to change the color in  <solid android:color="#33d1a3" />, then that is what that line is for, otherwise , you will need to use three different xmls, as you already are..

Comment: yes solid color i am talking  about i dont want create three different xml

Comment: go to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27698226/4336375
see if it helps you..

Comment: @SudhaKumari did you tried the answer i gave

Comment: yes i tried but its not working color no chnging

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change drawable color programmatically

`Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable); 
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new 
PorterDuffColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));`