# How to set the solid color and stroke color programatically in Selector Drawable?

Tags: android

I have a selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I want to set the solid color and stroke color programatically in this selector.How to achieve that.

Comment: Already has some answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165050/2553048

Comment: That gives class cast exception error,Since we are using StatelistDrawable not Gradient drawable.